# AngularJS : what's the difference between these two lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, binding

```
$scope.init = function() {
  return $scope.items = basketService.items;
};

ng-repeat = "item in items"
```

And working with $scope.items + refresh $scope.items with broadcasting.

OR

```
$scope.getItems = function() {
  return basketService.items;
};

ng-repeat = "item in getItems()"
```

Is copying basketService.items to $scope.items a must done or is it the same as getItems() (speed, memory...) ?

Comment: You will get more answers if you convert that CoffeeScript to JavaScript.

Comment: In the first example, `$scope.items = basketService.items`, you are not copying but rather just setting a reference.  As long as basketService.items is manipulated (e.g., use angular.copy() or splice() to alter `items` in the service) and not reset (i.e., something like this is NOT done: `items = newItemsArrayFromServer`), there is no need to refresh $scope.items -- it will always reference the service's array, and ng-repeat will notice any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a difference between them, and it is really just a matter of style.  Take a look at this (very crude and contrived) fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalzebra/92gA6/

Here is the very messy controller from that:

```
angular.module("foobar", []).controller("lol", function($scope) {
   $scope.items = ["loe", "le", "effe"];
    var blah = ["leoele", "elelkej", "elfkjflkje"];

    $scope.doStuff = function() {
      $scope.items.push("eee", "eeelkjf");  
    };

    $scope.getItems = function() {
        return blah;
    }

    $scope.doOtherStuff = function() {
      blah.push("elejlee'e");  
    };
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="foobar">
    <div ng-controller="lol">

       <b>First list:</b>
       <div ng-repeat="item in items">
           {{item}}
       </div>

       <b>Second list:</b>
       <div ng-repeat="item in getItems()">
           {{item}}
       </div>
        <button ng-click="doStuff()">Click me</button>
        <button ng-click="doOtherStuff()">Do Other stuff</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that both variants work, and both will give you two way binding etc.